# Check whether the quotient ring $R:=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ is a field or an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Given the quotient ring $R:=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$, I've to check whether it's a field or an integral domain.

I'd say that $R$ is a field and an integral domain because $(xy-z^²)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ (Eisenstein with $x \in \mathbb{C}[x,y][z]$).
However, I know that $R$ is not a field. I don't know what I've done wrong. Is my application of Eisenstein criteria false? How can I show that $R$ is not a field, but an integral domain?

Comment: $z$ is also irreducible, but $\Bbb C[x,y,z] / (z) \simeq \Bbb C[x,y]$ is not a field (since $x$ has no inverse, for example).

Comment: In your $R$ the element $\bar x$ is not invertible. If $\bar x\bar f=\bar 1$ then $xf-1\in(xy-z^2)$, hence $xf-1=(xy-z^2)g$. Now set $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: Why do I have to set x=y=z=0  in order to show that x has no inverse??

Comment: Is it because of the contradiction $-1 =0$.Could I also set $x=y=z=5$, for example?

Comment: @Thesinus I'm not sure that x=y=z=5 leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Another approach is to show that $R \simeq \mathbb{C}[s^2, t^2, st]$ i.e. the subring of $\mathbb{C}[s, t]$ of polynomials where each term has even degree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

$\mathbf C[X,Y,Z]$ is a U.F.D., so ideals generated by irreducible elements have height $1$. Can these ideals be maximal?

Comment: Why can't they be maximal? Have maximal ideals height greater than one?

Comment: For any field, $F[X,Y,Z]$ has Krull dimension $3$, and is catenary, so maximal ideals have height $3$.

Answer (score 5):

A quotient ring is a field if and only if the original ideal is maximal. Use the fact that $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ has natural gradings by degree; does $(xy-z^2)$ contain any elements of degree $1$?